# Boot a qcow2 image in Ganeti

Tags: disk-image, qcow2, ganeti

I am very confused on how Ganeti actually boots machines. My problem is quite simple.

I have a `qcow2` image in a machine and I want to boot it. How can I do it? I don't really understand the idea of using OS definitions and I can't find a clear documentation on explaining why I need to go through out all this process to just boot a VM.

Sorry for the tone, if someone can explain to me how and why...